# Schedule Javascript function to call every day at specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js

Good afternoon, I would like to call my javascript function every day at 8:55PM UTC. 
I was suggested to do if with node-schedule but I'm curious is node-schedule actually can exactly bind a time? Can I specify in node-schedule special time?
Script:

```
request('GET', 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY')
        .then((r1) => {
            var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

            var BTCdata = (x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD.volume_24h); // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

            console.log(BTCdata);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

    function request(method, url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
            xhr.onload = resolve;
            xhr.onerror = reject;
            xhr.send();
        });
    }
```

This script console.logs me a information about bitcoin volume every 24 hours.
Can I setup a schedule to call this script everyday at exactly 8:55PM UTC?
Looking for any solution, maybe not exactly with node-schedule, maybe it's not suitable for my task.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a job for cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) is the way to go for such a task, just run your script as background process and node-schedule will take care of executing your code at the exact specified time, here is an example of how you might implement it, for everyday at 8:55PM:

```
...
var schedule = require("node-schedule");

var j = schedule.scheduleJob("*/55 20 * * *", function () {
  request(
    "GET",
    "http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=YOUR-API-KEY"
  )
    .then((r1) => {
      var x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

      var BTCdata = x1.data.find((d) => d.symbol === "BTC").quote.USD
        .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

      console.log(BTCdata);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

function request(method, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = resolve;
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for advice and confirmation that i can use node-schedule.
I already bothered with error of require is not defined. Happens again with me.
As well did this */55 20 * * * is setting up the 8:55PM?

Comment: did you run `npm install node-schedule` in your app? `*/55 20 * * *` is the timing for `8:55PM`, you can check [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/55_20_*_*_*) for changing time as you want.

Comment: Please consider [accepting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find my answer useful :)

Comment: yes, of course run it. Have this error about require is not defined in so many situations already.